# <div> added to Views header (global unfiltered text) disappears with inspect element

Tags: views

I'm trying to wrap a  tag around some content in my View header but it's not working as intended.

I'm using the Global: Unfiltered text as the type of header content. I'm inserting the div like so:

```
<div class="some-class"><h2>header</h2></div>
```

It saves it alright and when I go back and view it it's still in there...but for some reason it doesn't show up in the HTML when I inspect element. The h2 tag shows up but not the div wrapped around it.

Thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your header (for quick testing purposes, so you don't need to add it to a css file)

```
<style>
 .some-class { border: solid red; }
</style>
```

To double check that indeed it's not there.

If it's not there (you don't see anything red), then try using **Global: Text area** instead and use Full HTML as your text format.

Comment: global: text area fixed it!